# Generate dynamic data to fill table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say that I have the table below:

> | Cod | Name
>
> | 0   |
>
> | 1   |
>
> | 2   |
>
> | 3   |
>
> | 4   |

What I want is to fill name column with "Name" + Cod, like this:

> | Cod | Name
>
> | 0   | Name0
>
> | 1   | Name1
>
> | 2   | Name2
>
> | 3   | Name3
>
> | 4   | Name4

It's for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT "Cod", 'Name'||CAST("Cod" AS varchar) AS "Name"
  FROM table;
```

If you already have column `Name`, just update:

```
UPDATE table SET "Name" = 'Name'||CAST("Cod" AS varchar);
```

Note, that you have to double-quote identifiers if you want to keep them as is (capitalized), otherwise they all are transfered to lowercase by PostgreSQL.

Comment: I would suggest cast(COD as varchar).  Text seems overkill for this application.

Comment: Just as a point of information, in PostgreSQL `text` and `varchar` (with no length limit) have the same implementation, and text is the generally preferred spelling. There is no advantage *within PostgreSQL* in using `varchar` here instead of `text`, although if you want code to port gracefully to systems where there is a difference, it might be useful.